# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol referenced in function _main visual c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, lnk2019

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this? I've looked online and changed settings on my visual C++, but it still doesn't work.

```
class store
{
public:
    int MainMenu();
    store();
private:
    int main;
};

class customer:store
{
public:
    int CustomerMenu();
    customer();
private:
    int cmenu;
};

class employee:store
{
public:
    int EmployeeMenu();
    employee();
private:
    int emenu;

};

int main()
{
    int main;
    store a;
    customer b;
employee c;
a.MainMenu();
if(main = 1)
{
    c.EmployeeMenu();
}
else if(main = 2)
{
    b.CustomerMenu();
}
else
{
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
}

int MainMenu()
{
    int main;
cout << "Choose an option: " << endl;
cout << " 1. Administration menu" << endl;
cout << " 2. Customer menu" << endl;
cout << " 3. Exit the program" << endl;
cin >> main;
return main;
}

int CustomerMenu()
{
int cmenu;
cout << " 1. Search Video" << endl;
cout << " 2. View Video Titles" << endl;
cout << " 3. Rent Video" << endl;
cout << " 4. Exit to the Main Menu" << endl;
cout << " 5. Exit the program" << endl;
cin >> cmenu;
return cmenu;

}

int EmployeeMenu()
{
int emenu;
    cout << " 1.  Store Information menu" << endl;
    cout << " 2.  Merchandise Information menu" << endl;
    cout << " 3.  Category Information menu" << endl;
    cout << " 4.  Customer Information menu" << endl;
    cout << " 5.  Employee Information menu" << endl;
    cout << " 6.  Rent a Video" << endl;
    cout << " 7.  Restock Video" << endl;
    cout << " 8.  Sales menu" << endl;
    cout << " 9.  Exit to Main Menu" << endl;
    cout << " 10. Exit the program" << endl;
cin >> emenu;
return emenu;

}

store::store()
{
main = 0;
}

customer::customer()
{
cmenu = 0;
}

employee::employee()
{
emenu = 0;
}
```

It gives me:

```
Store.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall customer::CustomerMenu(void)" (?CustomerMenu@customer@@QAEHXZ) referenced in function _main
1>Store.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall employee::EmployeeMenu(void)" (?EmployeeMenu@employee@@QAEHXZ) referenced in function _main
1>Store.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall store::MainMenu(void)" (?MainMenu@store@@QAEHXZ) referenced in function _main
```

Comment: why do you have a variable called `main`?

Comment: not to mention `if (main = 1)` will always be true. you mean `==`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're implementing `CustomerMenu()` and `EmployeeMenu()` as normal functions, not class members. The implementaitons should be;

```
int customer::CustomerMenu()
{
...

int employee::EmployeeMenu()
{
...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(main = 1)
{   //^^should be ==, same as the one below
    c.EmployeeMenu();
}
else if(main = 2)
{
    b.CustomerMenu();
}
```

Member functions should be defined with scope resolution operator:

```
int CustomerMenu()
```

should be:

```
int Customer::ustomerMenu()
```

Minor point:

```
class employee:store
```

Here you used `private inheritance`, you really need to think about whether you need it or not.

Comment: (The OP is novice. Obviously he *doesn't* need private inheritance.)
the syntax should be `class employee : public store`. but it sounds unlikely that an `employee` will inherit from `store`.

Comment: @Elazar I totally agree with you.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your input. As Elazar stated I am a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

Your member function implementations need to be defined correctly.  For example:

```
int CustomerMenu()
```

Should be:

```
int  customer::CustomerMenu(void)
```

And so forth.